# Focus not going to next page in Datatable Grid

Tags: datatables-1.10

I'm using J-query data-table (Grid) for entry pagination true and set 10 records per page. After 10 records generated second page but focus not going to next page.

[image]

Comment: Hard to debug a screenshot ...

Answer (score 0):

finally i got the answer in click event,

its click next button after 10 records.

//page navigation after 10 reords

```
 var totRecCount = $('#tblDtl').DataTable().rows().count();
    for (var i = 0; i < totRecCount; i++) {
        if (i >= 10)
            $('#tblDtl_next').trigger('click');
    }
```